# How to use EWS on hosted Exchange with Impersonation?

Tags: c#, impersonation, exchangewebservices

I want to create a service which to crawl all inboxes of all users on a hosted exchange server (“myclient.onmicrosoft.com”) via EWS.

This already works well when I connect to on-premise exchange servers in the same domain. But when I try to connect this service to a hosted exchange, it throws  401 (wrong authorization) errors. Of course, this is a different domain as the hosted exchange server.
My service runs on an on-premise server and uses a “god-mode” user to impersonalise to all active directory users. My question is: How to connect the users of my on-premise system correctly to the hosted exchange in a different domain?

Note: It  works when I use the credentials directly and the impersonation way does work on on-premise installations.

What I did so far (and I wonder of this is the right way to do it): On our on-premise server I created a domain “myclient.onmicrosoft.com” just like on the hosted server and an AD user with the same name and password as on the hosted exchange (called “mytest@myclient.onmicrosoft.com”).

On my crawler service I did:

1. I got all AD users in our on premise server

   ```
   var allUsers = SearchAllActiveDirectoryUsers();

         foreach (DataRow user in allUsers.Rows)
         {
                   String domainName = (String)user["DomainName"];
                   String samAccountName = (String)user["SamAccountName"];
                   String principalName = (String)user["PrincipalName"];
                   String principalDomainName = (String)user["PrincipalDomainName"];
                   String mail = (String)user["Mail"];
           }
   ```
2. Then for each AD user I connected the user with the exchange service like this:

   ```
   ExchangeService ex = new ExchangeService(version);
       ex.Url = new Uri(“https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx”);
       ex.Credentials = new WebCredentials("mytest@myclient.onmicrosoft.com", “XXX”, " myclient.onmicrosoft.com"); 
       // THIS DOES WORK CORRECTLY!
       ex.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.PrincipalName, “mytest@myclient.onmicrosoft.com”);
       //this does NOT work!
   ```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the credentials of your "god-mode" user, but set the ImpersonatedUserId to the AD user. Something like:

```
ex.Credentials = new WebCredentials("account_with_impersonation_rights@myclient.onmicrosoft.com", "password");
ex.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.PrincipalName, "mytest@myclient.onmicrosoft.com");
```

When you connect to Office 365 via EWS, you always need to supply credentials. You can't use `UseDefaultCredentials = true`.

Comment: Thanks Jason! I only have a god-mode user for our on-premise domain, but not for the remote domain. Does Office 365 offer a way to create such admin users?

Comment: Sure does! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722376(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: @JasonJohnston I dont understand what should realistically go were you have mytest@myclient.onmicrosoft.com